# tkiz matrix bigger arrow heads

Tags: tikz-arrows, tkz-graph

I am wondering if is it possible to increase the size of the arrowheads. it's not visible when it's printed.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        draw,
        text width=4em,
        text badly centered,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
        -latex,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
|[cloud]|    {phase scheduler}                                                       &                                                                                   \\
|[decision]| {detect circularity}                                                    &                                                                                   \\
|[block]|    {non-circular phase scheduler}                                          & |[block]| {circular phase scheduler}                                              \\
|[block]|    {find component containing single chunk of half-left for this phase}    & |[block]| {find component containing both half-left and half-right for this phase}\\
|[block]|    {schedule half-left for this phase}                                     & |[block]| {schedule half-left from this component}                                \\
|[block]|    {find next inner component ready to schedule}                           & |[block]| {find next chunk ready to schedule from this component}                 \\
|[block]|    {schedule next available chunk in this in this inner component}         & |[block]| {schedule chunk}                                                        \\
|[block]|    {find component containing a single chunk of half-right for this phase} & |[block]| {schedule half-right from this component}                               \\
|[block]|    {schedule half-right for this phase}                                    &                                                                                   \\
};

\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->, dashed] (m-2-1) edge  (m-3-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-8-1) edge (m-9-1);

\draw [rectangle connector=2.5cm, dashed] (m-2-1) to node[descr] {\emph{circular phase}} (m-3-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-3-2) edge (m-4-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-4-2) edge (m-5-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-5-2) edge (m-6-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-6-2) edge (m-7-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-7-2) edge (m-8-2);

\draw [rectangle connector=2.75cm] (m-7-1) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-6-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=2.75cm] (m-7-2) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-6-2);

\draw [rectangle connector=-3.5cm] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-1-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-2.55cm] (m-8-2) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Flow chart describing different pieces of SCC chunk scheduling}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see ch. 16.3, esp. 16.3.2 Scaling. It's better to move your arrow-definitions into a statement within tikzset or as option after tikzpicture. It's too early for me to rework your code this way ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `arrows.meta` library which allow you to change the size of arrow heads easily. I would suggest that you delete all instances of `>=latex` and define the style of the arrow heads only once. Also, replace `-latex` by `->` in the definition of the `rectangle connector` style to get the same arrow heads everywhere:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows.meta,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
    >={Latex[width=5pt]},
    decision/.style={
        diamond,
        draw,
        text width=4em,
        text badly centered,
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    block/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        text width=10em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners
    },
    cloud/.style={
        draw,
        ellipse,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    descr/.style={
        fill=white,
        inner sep=2.5pt
    },
    connector/.style={
        ->,
        font=\scriptsize
    },
    rectangle connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
        pos=0.5
    },
    rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
    straight connector/.style={
        connector,
        to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center} ]{
|[cloud]|    {phase scheduler}                                                       &                                                                                   \\
|[decision]| {detect circularity}                                                    &                                                                                   \\
|[block]|    {non-circular phase scheduler}                                          & |[block]| {circular phase scheduler}                                              \\
|[block]|    {find component containing single chunk of half-left for this phase}    & |[block]| {find component containing both half-left and half-right for this phase}\\
|[block]|    {schedule half-left for this phase}                                     & |[block]| {schedule half-left from this component}                                \\
|[block]|    {find next inner component ready to schedule}                           & |[block]| {find next chunk ready to schedule from this component}                 \\
|[block]|    {schedule next available chunk in this in this inner component}         & |[block]| {schedule chunk}                                                        \\
|[block]|    {find component containing a single chunk of half-right for this phase} & |[block]| {schedule half-right from this component}                               \\
|[block]|    {schedule half-right for this phase}                                    &                                                                                   \\
};

\path [->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [->, dashed] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\path [->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path [->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
\path [->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
\path [->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
\path [->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
\path [->] (m-8-1) edge (m-9-1);

\draw [rectangle connector=2.5cm, dashed] (m-2-1) to node[descr] {\emph{circular phase}} (m-3-2);
\path [->] (m-3-2) edge (m-4-2);
\path [->] (m-4-2) edge (m-5-2);
\path [->] (m-5-2) edge (m-6-2);
\path [->] (m-6-2) edge (m-7-2);
\path [->] (m-7-2) edge (m-8-2);

\draw [rectangle connector=2.75cm] (m-7-1) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-6-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=2.75cm] (m-7-2) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-6-2);

\draw [rectangle connector=-3.5cm] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-1-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-2.55cm] (m-8-2) to node[descr] {\emph{loop}} (m-1-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Flow chart describing different pieces of SCC chunk scheduling}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]